# Laravel 5.3 - Custom validators

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have this validator for input called "name":

```
Regex:/^[A-Za-z0-9\\s\\-\\/,.]*$/|min:5|max:50
```

But, I want to use this validator in multiple forms in my website.
How can i do this without to copy this validator in all the forms validations?

My database contains table called "settings", every row presents setting of the website. Each setting contain Json code that save the setting data.
I want to create custom validator that check if the input value equals to one of the values in the Json code in my database.
I have Json code like this:

```
[{"US":"United States", "UK":"United Kingdom"}]
```

And I want to check if the value of the input equals to one of the values in the Json code. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I know you said, across your website. However, I would think that you're ensuring that the use of forms using the same validators are relatively within the same state. 
Here's an example that helped me get to where I needed to be! I hope it serves as a good enough guide!:

MessageBag documentation here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#error-messages-and-views

**public function postLogin(Request $request)**

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email' => 'required|email', 'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return redirect($this->loginPath())->withErrors($validator, 'loginErrors');
    }

    $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }

    return redirect($this->loginPath())
        ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
        ->withErrors([
            'email' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
        ], 'loginErrors');
}
```

Now you can look for errors inside of your view:

```
@if (!$errors->loginErrors->isEmpty())
<div class="form_error_login">
    <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br>    <br>
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->loginErrors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
</div>
@endif
```

For the Modals (if you use them):

```
<script>
    $findError = $('div').find ('div');
    if ( $findError.hasClass('form_error_login')){
        $('#modalLogin').foundation('reveal', 'open');
    }
    if ( $findError.hasClass('form_error_register')){
        $('#modalRegister').foundation('reveal', 'open');
    }
</script>
```

**Reference:**

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/authcontroller-loginregistration-on-same-page